# React-Toastify Module not found

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**When I tried to use react toast it shows this error below.**

Before trying this toast I have installed with this command:

`npm install --save react-toastify`

> Showing Error in Google Chrome Console:

```
ERROR in ./src/Pages/Login/Login/Login.js 12:0-55 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-toastify' in 'C:\projects\toffpark-footwear-inventory-client\src\Pages\Login\Login'
```

I'm working with `React, bootstrap, javascript`

Answer (score 0):

**Please use following commands:**

First install using this and import it.

```
npm i react-toastify

import {ToastContainer,toast} from 'react-toastify'
```

and while return add this

```
<ToastContainer />
```

And use it like this

```
<div>
 <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={notify}>
                    Show live alert
 </button>
 <ToastContainer />
</div>
```